# Async call in nodejs using promise

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

i need to send bulk sms using php, so the nodejs is connected with socket i am sending data to nodejs using socket to send bulk sms and the required the result as send items, means how many sms sent successfully or not i am pushing the response in an array then i will emit the array to client for further calculation but the issue is that nodejs work synchronized so i use promise to do this job async but getting array null

```js
function getData(smsDetails) {
  var results = [];
  var sendLocalSmsPromis = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    for (var a = 0; a < smsDetails.data.contacts.length; a++) {
      var contact = smsDetails.data.contacts[a].phone;
      var dialCode = contact.substring(0, 2);
      if (dialCode == 92) {
        localSms(smsDetails.data.message, contact, smsDetails.data.senderId.name, function (response) {
          if (response.orginalResponse.Data.hasOwnProperty("id")) {
            //sent successfully
          } else {
            var smsLength = generalHelper.calculateSmsLength(response.message);
            var sentItemsData = {
              user_id: smsDetails.data.user_id,
              number: response.contact,
              message: response.message,
              length: smsLength,
              status: 0,
              type: 'portal',
              date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:ss:mm")
            };
            results.push(sentItemsData);
          }

        });

      }

    }
    resolve(results);
  });

  return sendLocalSmsPromis;
}


socket.on("sendSms", function (smsDetails) {

  var data = getData(smsDetails);
  data.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // socket.emit("smsResponse",response);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`localSms` function is asynchronous and for-loop is synchronous. 
Convert your `localSms` into a promise returning function.

```
function getData(smsDetails) {
    var results = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < smsDetails.data.contacts.length; a++) {
        var contact = smsDetails.data.contacts[a].phone;
        var dialCode = contact.substring(0, 2);
        if (dialCode == 92) {
            results.push(localSmsPromisified(smsDetails.data.message, contact, smsDetails.data.senderId.name))
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(results);
}

function localSmsPromisified(message = "", contact = "", name = "") {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return localSms(message, contact, name, function (response) {
            if (response.orginalResponse.Data.hasOwnProperty("id")) {
                return resolve({ alreadySent: 1 });
            } else {
                var smsLength = generalHelper.calculateSmsLength(response.message);
                var sentItemsData = {
                    user_id: smsDetails.data.user_id,
                    number: response.contact,
                    message: response.message,
                    length: smsLength,
                    status: 0,
                    type: 'portal',
                    date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:ss:mm")
                };
                return resolve(sentItemsData);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[Refer this article to understand the concepts](https://www.topcoder.com/callbacks-promises-async-await/)